Does every collection of edges between two sets of vertices in a plane have a "perimeter" edge suitable for induction inwards?
Joel Hamkins posted this nice problem: https://x.com/JDHamkins/status/1790582025977577591
I quote:

Suppose you have 1000 white points and 1000 black points in the plane, no three collinear. Can you draw segments connecting them in pairs, from white to black, using each point just once, without any edges crossing?

I found a solution which was to bisect the plane with a straight line through some black/white pair, then rotate it until you have an equal number of black and white on one side of the line.  Once you do so, you can repeat the process for each side of the bisector, and continue by induction until you are done.
You will always get to a point in the rotation where the black/white are equal on one side for the same reason that every smooth end of a cylinder has two level points directly opposite each other.  I'm not totally sure of this argument because the rules of rotation need defining such that you only change the difference in the counts of black and white by exactly two at each rotation, and I'm not clear whether that's guaranteed to be possible.
Anyway... the above is just background to the question.  Moving on to the point of this question:  Discussing this with my daughter, she proposed another solution. She thinks that you can start at the perimeter and work inwards by induction.
Question
Is there a suitable definition of a "perimeter* edge such that a) one always exists, and b) one can proceed inwards by induction until you are done?
My thoughts
It will be sufficient if there is always a black/white pair of vertices, whose bisector partitions the entire remainder of vertices into the same half of the plane.
I think there will always be such a pair.  Pick an arbitrary pair.  If the half-plane having the fewest remaining has more than zero, move one end of your line on to a vertex that side, keeping the vertex on one black and white. Continue until you reach the edge and you have found a perimeter edge.  Now make it permanent and repeat with the remaining collection of vertices.

Are you asking about the validity of your angle rotation argument, or just about the perimeter edge, or a combination of both approaches?  Your "my thoughts" don't seem to line up with "Question".  $\quad$ Some of your phrases don't quite make sense to me. EG "whose bisector partitions the entire remainder of vertices into the same half of the plane."  I get that you want something like "whose bisector partitions the remaining vertices, such that in each half of the plane there is an equal number of black and white vertices". However, that does not come through.

Unless I misunderstand, this diagram shows an example with no perimeter edge to take (except that it has $10$ instead of $1000$ points of each color. Is that right?

@MishaLavrov yes I agree the naive notion of a perimeter edge defined as partitioning the plane into two halves, one empty, fails. I had come up with this counterexample myself, after writing the question. But I still think there is a valid definition of a "perimeter" edge.

@CalvinLin in this question I have moved away from the original idea of partitioning the plane into two sides, each containing black points equal in number to the white points in that half. I mention that out of interest and to highlight that there is another way.  But this question is asking about another way - it asks if there is a valid way of defining a "perimeter" and work inwards by induction.

@it'sahirecarbaby Re " this question is asking about another way", I think you should make that much clearer. EG You claim that " I have moved away from the original idea ... I mention that out of interest and to highlight that there is another way", but with the phrasing of "I'm not totally sure of this argument ..." and "whose bisector partitions the entire remainder of vertices into the same half of the plane.", makes me think otherwise. This might just be my personal preference. $\quad$ EG You should also clarify "But I still think there is a valid definition of a "perimeter" edge."

@CalvinLin ok thanks for the input I've made that clearer.
